# How to derive the following formula ∃x∃yP(x,y)⇒∃y∃xP(x,y)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

This is an exercise I have at university, Math. Logics, Axiomatic Theory.
I would aprecciate any help, because I don't understand this subject. Any sophisticated answers are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apply Existential Elimination twice followed by Existential Introduction twice.

Comment: For more details, we need details about the proof system (axioms+rules) of your textbook.

Comment: 12.3. Deriving laws
If we remember the definition with general induction (Chapter 3), then
In asking the axiom we have defined only the set S0. That is not the whole theory T. To define the whole theory T, we need to fix export laws.
(i) Modus ponens: A, A ⇒ B / B
(ii) General purpose frameworks (formula A does not contain the variable x):
A ⇒ B (x) / A ⇒ ∀yB (y),
B (x) ⇒ A / ∃yB (y) ⇒ A
This is a small part from my textbook, sorry for translation, the bokk is in latvian and I really don't know of this part somehow helps the question.

Comment: The exercise formulation really does sound that simple: to derive the formula ∃x∃yP(x,y)⇒∃y∃xP(x,y), but it doesn't say how exatly I should do it.

Comment: It's semantically trivial, so with completeness ....

Comment: You have to derive $P(x,y) \to ∃y∃xP(x,y)$ and then apply the rule in (ii).